# Error when returning a tuple to multiple dcc.Download Outputs

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

The example is a significantly reduced version of my app.

The app functions correctly but upon initiation, it throws the traceback below.

I am attempting to return a tuple of `dcc.Download` to two different Outputs. I have tried unpacking the tuple and putting each element in the `return` as well but still get the same error.

What I don't understand is how it states that I am returning a `None` type, when I am actually returning a tuple.

Traceback:

```
dash._grouping.SchemaTypeValidationError: Schema: [<Output `rprt1.data`>, <Output `rprt2.data`>]
Path: ()
Expected type: (<class 'tuple'>, <class 'list'>)
Received value of type <class 'NoneType'>: None
```

Functioning Code:

```
import dash
from dash import html, Input, Output
from dash import dcc
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Download(id='rprt1'),
    dcc.Download(id='rprt2'),
    html.Button('A', id='button', n_clicks=0)
])

def multi_dnwld(df1, df2, names):
    tup = (df1, df2)
    dwnld = []
    for df, name in zip(tup, names):
        filename = name + ' - ' + '.csv'
        dwnld.append(dcc.send_data_frame(df.to_csv, filename, index=False))
    dwnld = tuple(dwnld)
    return dwnld

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns = ['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns = ['a', 'b'])

@app.callback(
    Output('rprt1', 'data'),
    Output('rprt2', 'data'),
    Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_callback=True
)
def summary(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks>0:
        names = ['Sum1', 'Sum2']
        return multi_dnwld(df1, df2, names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when `n_clicks` is equal to 0?

```py
def summary(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks>0:
        names = ['Sum1', 'Sum2']
        return multi_dnwld(df1, df2, names)
```

Your `if` condition is then `False`, so it does not enter that block. You have no other code in this function, so Dash uses the Python default return value of `None`. This probably only happens once on app load. Just add an `else` condition to handle this case and you'll be good.